# Concatenate 3 strings with separator

Tags: kotlin

```
Write a function that concatenates three strings into one using a special separator. If the separator is not specified, it is a single space.
```

Suppose you have a standard input.

Concatenate the letters 1, 2, and 3.
Insert a fourth input separator between the characters in 1-2-3.

However, if a specific keyword is entered, it will be output as a half-width space.

The following is my code.

```kotlin
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val input = Array(4){scanner.next()}

    if (input[3] == "NO SEPARATOR"){
        println(" ")
    }else{
        input[3] == input[3]
    }
    println("$input[0]$input[3]$input[1]$input[3]$input[2]")
}
```

```kotlin
//Sample Input

abc
def
ghi
NO SEPARATOR
```

```kotlin
Sample Output

abc def ghi
```

I can't think of a solution.

Comment: `it will be output as a half-width space.` - what does this mean?

Comment: what's wrong with the output you get now? seems like it is exactly what you want.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. Could not get a specific string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be reading based off lines, which means you don't need a scanner, you can use [`readLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html). Secondly, you can use [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/join-to-string.html) for adding a separator in between:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = Array(3) { readLine()!! }
    var sep = readLine()!!
    if (sep == "NO SEPARATOR") {
        sep = " "
    }
    println(input.joinToString(sep))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use + for concatenation.

```
String result=""
for(i in yourArrayOfWords){
result=result + i + separator;
}
```